# PHP: Generate object title for JSON using array_push

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to generate a multi-layered JSON file using php's array function (for 3 separate arrays).  I'm essentially using 3 different arrays in php to generate the one   Here is the basic code I am using in php:

```
$full_array = array();
...
$results_array('step1');
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
     $add_array = array();
     $add_array['total'] = $ga->getResults();
     array_push($results_array, $add_array);
endforeach;
array_push($full_array, $results_array);
echo json_encode($full_array)
```

This results in the following:

```
[
   [
      "step1",
         {
            "total": "...."
         }
   ]
]
```

However, I'm trying to get that "step1" before the brace, so it should look like the following:

```
[
   "step1",
      [
           {
             "total": "...."
           }
      ]
]
```

Does anybody know how to get the latter format using PHP?  I've searched for this answer everywhere but could not find it anywhwere - apologies if there is a duplicate answer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PHP has shorthand for pushing onto an array: `$array[] = $var_to_push`

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `$full_array` and do:

```
echo json_encode($results_array);
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen & G-Nugget.  I guess I should have elaborated, the reason I hae the $full_array is that there are multiple loops that I will be using to push into the $full_array.